# Why is the Embed Tag Used in HTML?

Tags: html

Why is the Embed Tag Used in HTML? Why not using like "CSS" or "XML"?

I need someone to explain why

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you clarify? `<embed>` isn't really used any longer as far as I can see, and I don't see what it has to do with CSS or XML exactly.

Comment: What I mean is why just HTML and not others

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It allows adding an external resource (video, text, image, plug-in...) to your web page by creating a container that can receive such external data streams. However, it is often better to use more specific tags like `<img>`, `<iframe>`, or `<video>`.

It is also possible to achieve a similar embedding functionality with XML, but use cases are less common.
However, CSS is for style only: it changes the appearance of DOM objects on the page.